# How to enable query validator in API gatway on yml file - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm trying to enable a request validator in API Gateway using a serverless yml file, but I don't find a option for this in the documentation: [Serverless Doc](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-schema-validators).
In the AWS terminal, I solved this problem, but for me is more interesting if using a .yml file.

Tutorial AWS: [AWS validator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-set-up.html#api-gateway-request-validation-setup-using-rest-api)

[Option in AWS terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwK8R.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a community-supported plugin that allows you to add the AWS Request Validator API Gateway functions to your Serverless project: https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-reqvalidator-plugin/

*Here is an example from OP*

```
plugins:
  - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
service: lambda-teste

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  runtime: nodejs12.x

functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: handler.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: handler
          reqValidatorName: onlyHead
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                name: true

resources:
  Resources:
    onlyHead:  
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator"
      Properties:
        Name: 'only-head'
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: false
        ValidateRequestParameters: true
```

Comment: not working on me :/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, if you're looking for body validation you could also use the built-in request validation based on draft-04 of JSON schema. It's built into the Serverless Framework.

Docs - https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#request-schema-validators
Example - https://github.com/fernando-mc/schema-validation-demo

Comment: No, this is util for body request. I needed a validator for queryStrings...